# Spring 4.2: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I recently upgraded from Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE to Spring 4.2.3.RELEASE.

When running my unit tests, I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.<clinit>(MockMvcResultHandlers.java:44)
```

And:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers
```

Line 44 of `MockMvcResultHandlers` looks like this:

```
private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MockMvcResultHandlers.class.getPackage().getName());
```

I confirmed that I have commons-logging 1.2 as a dependency in Maven.

Any ideas of what the issue could be?

Thanks!

Comment: I just told maven surefire to print the full stack trace and it looks like a NullPointerException is happening at line 44 but I'm a bit unsure why... Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.<clinit>(MockMvcResultHandlers.java:44)
 ... 71 more

Answer (score 1):

I've confirmed that the NullPointerException is coming from MockMvcResultHandlers.class.getPackage().

Update: From what I've read, some people are saying that using the maven-surefire-plugin with a forkCount greater than 0 might fix it. Unfortunately, in my particular situation, I can't update the forkCount to verify that.

Update: I opened a JIRA against Spring and they said it will be fixed in 4.2.4:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13802

Answer (score 0):

You might have a conflicting `spring-test` version included by another dependency. I would try to identify whether other dependencies are importing a different version. You can do this in intelliJ, if you use it (and probably other IDEs do it but that's what I use), and you can also do a maven dependency tree. I find both methods useful.

[Maven Dependency Tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html):

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose > tree.txt
```

or, to isolate your specific dependency,

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=spring-test > tree.txt
```

I find it useful to output to a file and then search through it using `less` or some other tool.

In IntelliJ:

In the Maven Projects tab at right, expand all (CTRL+PLUS in Windows) and look through the dependencies of dependencies and see if you see commons-logging. This is obviously more of a brute force method.

Comment: Nothing really stands out after running mvn dependency:tree.  It shows commons-logging 1.2 being favoured over all others.

Comment: You might not have a dependency version conflict. But it looks from your errors as though the problem is not with logging, but with MockMvcResultHandlers.